# What is the cost/benefit of using mongoid versus activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid

Google searching leads me to questions looking to use mongoid and activerecord in parallel. I've seen a lot of questions specific to mongoid and a lot of questions specific to activerecord, but none comparing them.

I guess the question is, what are the benefits of running the mongoid adapter with rails for mongoid db versus running activerecord with mysql?

Comment: do you mean mongoid / mongodb vs activerecord / postgres | mysql or something? Is this an adapter question or db-choice question?

Comment: I perceive a slight tinge of subjectivity. Is it more about the points where they concur and differ?

Comment: Maybe my ignorance is showing. Not trying to be subjective. I'll try to be more clear with an edit.

Comment: do you want a relational db?

Comment: I don't mind either one, I would just like to know the benefits of each before I dive too deeply into one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoid and ActiveRecord are both [database ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (technically speaking, Mongoid is a ODM, but that's another topic). However, Mongoid targets only the MongoDB database, while ActiveRecord targets relational databases such as PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLServer.

For this reason, it's not really possible to compare them. In fact, they are not one a replacement of the other. Which one you use, depends on the database behind your application.

You can compare ActiveRecord with DataMapper or Sequel. Likewise you can compare Mongoid with MongoMapper (actually you could, but there is no comparison because the last one is almost dead).

For this reason, I believe the question doesn't have sense in that way. I assume people would choose the ORM because of the database, not the database because of the ORM.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot more clear. I was under the impression that Mongoid was an ORM that would target relational databases, and for that reason I was wondering what the difference was.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about Object Document Mappers (ODM) and Object Relational Mappers (ORM).

Mongoid is an ODM for MongoDB.
That is a NoSQL database.

ActiveRecord is an ORM for PostgreSQL (and a few others).
This are SQL databases.

So the real question for you is:

> Should I use a SQL or a NoSQL database?

Once you answer that, you can pick an ODM or ORM.

Comment: Active record is an ORM, Mongoid is an ODM, "D and M" => "Document and Relational"

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoDB if you need

- ridiculously fast writes
- fast reads against a simple index
- either no schema, or the kind of schema that SQL would force you to implement by hand anyway because SQL couldn't comprehend it

Use SQL if you need

- slow writes
- adequate reads of arbitrarily complex relations of data
- a traditional schema of tables, records, and keys

Both systems support ACID & CRUD, so don't use either of them if you also don't need those!